# Why Shopify api doesn't retrieve orders from store?

Tags: c#, asp.net, shopify

I use shopify API and ShopifSharp c# library(https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp). I manually create orders and give it status "fulfilled". Now I just want to give this orders , but I get Count = . 
My code is simple:

```
var service = new OrderService(product.ShopifyShopName, shopifyAccessToken);
 IEnumerable<Order> orders = await service.ListAsync(); // count = 0       
 var paidOrders = orders.Where(x => x.FulfillmentStatus.Equals("fulfilled"));
```

It retrieves orders when they have status "unfulfilled" but why? I use development store for this objectives

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to change the status directly in the order, instead use [Fulfillment Admin API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/shipping_and_fulfillment/fulfillment) after you create the order. So with this API you can change the fulfillment status of the order, and after that you can retrieve the fulfilled orders correctly.

Answer (score -1):

By default Shopify retrieves a list of orders (OPEN Orders by default, use status=any for all orders).

For more info please look at here: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#index

Comment: Please do not roll back good edits, Rohit. There was too much formatting here, a salutation that we discourage, chatty material that is redundant, grammar mistakes, and case errors.